# Can anyone explain this function and significance of 86400?

Tags: contract-development, timestamp

I have a function which is used to check if 90 days have been passed or not after staking, but I can't figure out why 86400 is mentioned, like is it seconds or minutes or anything else and how can I change that 90 days to any other value of my choice.

```
        function getTimePassedSinceStake(address _owner, uint256 _index)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return (block.timestamp - userInfo[_owner][_index].stakeTime) / 86400;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block.timestamp#block-and-transaction-properties) :

> block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp as seconds since unix
> epoch

So :

```
block.timestamp - userInfo[_owner][_index].stakeTime
```

Is the number of seconds between `stakeTime` and `block.timestamp`. Dividing by 86400 is dividing by the number of seconds in a day (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours = 86400)

```
 return (block.timestamp - userInfo[_owner][_index].stakeTime) / 86400;
```

returns the number of whole days between `stakeTime` and `block.timstamp` this has nothing to do with 90 days here.

An alternative syntax could be :

```
return (block.timestamp - userInfo[_owner][_index].stakeTime) / 1 days;
```

---

> how can I change that 90 days to any other value of my choice.

I found a contract with the same code [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe5708E226EFd13404934CdfAdD5ce392dF86B1A1#code), that has the following `unstake` function with a 1 day limit :

```
function unStake(uint256 _index) external {
    address unStaker = msg.sender;
    UserInfo storage userDetails = userInfo[unStaker][_index];
    uint256 tokenId1 = userDetails.tokenId1;
    uint256 timePassedSinceStaked = getTimePassedSinceStake(
        unStaker,
        _index
    );
    require(
        timePassedSinceStaked >= 1,
        "You can not unstake before 1 day"
    );
    userDetails = userInfo[unStaker][userInfo[unStaker].length - 1];
    userInfo[unStaker].pop();

    ERC721.safeTransferFrom(address(this), unStaker, tokenId1, "");
   

    GemToken.claimByLuckyDragon(unStaker, 0);
    emit UnStakedLuckyDragon(
        unStaker,
        tokenId1,
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

Here it is limiting to 1 day of waiting time, by changing :

```
require(
    timePassedSinceStaked >= 1,
    "You can not unstake before 1 day"
);
```

to :

```
require(
    timePassedSinceStaked >= 90,
    "You can not unstake before 90 day"
);
```

It would require 90 days, of course you can set the value of your choice.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

ETH contracts use Unix time:

https://www.epochconverter.com
*The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT)*